# How to upload to Firebase Database such that it sorts by timestamp and not alphabetically

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

When a user takes a picture in my app, it gets uploaded to Storage and then the download link is saved to the Database. On a different VC, all these images are displayed in a gallery.

The issue is that when a new image is uploaded, Firebase sorts the children alphabetically. [image]

[image]

How do I upload an image by timestamp so that the newest image appears on the bottom? Keep in mind the snapshot.key values are the titles of the images, so I can't change those values.

This is how Im uploading the images

```
 func savePhotoStorage(){
    //replace spaces with _
    let title = textField.text!.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "_")
    let imageRef = storageRef.child(self.section).child(self.AU).child("Photos").child(title + ".jpg")

    if let dataImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image!, 1){

        let uploadTask = imageRef.putData(dataImage, metadata: nil, completion : { (metadata, error) in
            if error != nil{
                print(error)
                return
            }
            if let downloadPath = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString{
                self.pushtoDB(path: downloadPath,type:"Photos",title: title)
                print(metadata?.downloadURL())
            }
            else{
                print("No metadata available")
            }
        })
        uploadTask.resume()
        textField.text = ""
        //captureSession.stopRunning()
        //previewLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
    }
}
```

This is how the gallery is populating them

```
func loadImages(){
    newImageHandle = databaseRef.observe(DataEventType.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let _ = snapshot.value as? String {

            let imageView = UIImageView()
            let url = URL(string: snapshot.value as! String)
            let resource = ImageResource(downloadURL: url!, cacheKey: snapshot.value as? String)
            imageView.kf.indicatorType = .activity
            imageView.kf.setImage(with: resource)
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

            let label = UILabel()
            //label.text = imageArray[i]
            let title = snapshot.key.replacingOccurrences(of: "_", with: " ")
            label.text = title
            label.font = UIFont(name: "ScienceFair", size: 30)
            label.textAlignment = .center
            label.textColor = UIColor.white
            label.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
            label.sizeToFit()

            let width = UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.width/2
            let xPosition = width * CGFloat(self.i)
            imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: 0, width: self.mainScrollView.frame.width, height: self.mainScrollView.frame.height)
            label.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: 10, width: label.intrinsicContentSize.width, height: label.intrinsicContentSize.height)
            label.center = CGPoint(x: xPosition+self.view.center.x, y: 30)

            self.mainScrollView.contentSize.width = self.mainScrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(self.i+1)
            self.mainScrollView.addSubview(imageView)
            self.mainScrollView.addSubview(label)
            self.mainScrollView.autoresizingMask = .flexibleHeight

            self.i = self.i+1
        }

    })
}
```

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data

Comment: Maybe I was unclear. I wish to define some rules when uploading the image that allows to upload by timestamp. If I query the data when downloading, it adds time when populating the gallery, which I want to avoid. Instead Id rather add that time in the async call when uploading

Comment: What you just said sounds different from your original question.  I suggest you edit your question to describe clearly 1) what you're trying to accomplish 2) what you've tried so far to achieve that, and 3) the specific problem you're running into with that.

Comment: Alright, Ive added that information. Do you have an idea of how to solve this?

Comment: It looks like you haven't tried to store any timestamps in the database and order records by them according to those timestamps with the techniques listed in the first link.